# APC Back-UPS works fine during power outage but turns off when power is restored

Tags: ups

I have been facing a problem with sudden shutdowns of my PC without any warning. When this happens, the APC Back-UPS (RS 500) emits a long constant beep and the indicator light of the UPS is off. This has happened twice during the day, usually after the computer has been running for three to four hours. When I restart my PC and the UPS after a few minutes, everything works fine again. My PC is very basic, so overloading is out of the question.

I decided to test the UPS on another computer without running Windows (i.e. on the BIOS screen). When I switched off the power from the mains, the PC ran fine on battery back-up. But I noticed something very strange. When I restored the power from the mains, the computer monitor turned off for a second before turning back on. The next time I tried the same test while running Windows: the UPS continued to provide battery back-up when I switched off the power from the mains. But this time, when I restored the main power, the computer shut down suddenly and the UPS emitted a long constant beep without any indicator light.

This is very strange, the UPS seems to be running during a power outage test but it fails when the power is restored! Otherwise, my computer shuts down suddenly after three-four hours of continuous usage accompanied by the same constant long beep of the UPS.

I'd really appreciate any guidance from the experienced members here. The battery is not that old and was replaced in August 2021.

Comment: Are you sure nothing but the PC is plugged into the UPS's battery backed outlets? This really looks like an overload. Does the overload light come on at the very beginning of the continuous beep?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Only my PC and the LCD monitor are connected to the two battery-backed outlets of the UPS? It is definitely not an overload. It works properly for a few hours until suddenly everything shuts down. During testing, the UPS provided proper battery backup but when power was restored, the UPS failed with long constant beep. There is no overload light indication, it just shuts down suddenly with a constant long beep.